# Same IP list for multiple ingresses as a whitelist-source-range config

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have multiple ingresses that I want to attach the same IP list as a whitelist-source.
I can't use this list in the ConfigMap for the ingress-controller as it serves other ingresses as well. What would be a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

*Updated answer for the updated question:*

Yes, you can apply it to a single 'Ingress' by using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` annotation. For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "CIDR1,CIDR2,CIDR3"
spec:
  rules:
...
```

*Original answer for the original question:*

Yes, you can. Essentially, the 'Ingresses' will use the same ingress controller as long as they have the ingress controller annotation. For example, for an Nginx ingress controller, an Ingress would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
...
```

Then on the ConfigMap you can add something like this:

```
data:
  ...
  whitelist-source-range: "CIDR1,CIDR2,CIDR3"
  ...
```

Comment: Sorry , i meant that i cannot use the configmap option because it will affect other ingresses aswell (ingresses that shouldnt use the whitelist-source-range annotation).

Answer (score 0):

```
    whitelist-source-range: >- 
      "{{- $.Values.ingress.CIDR1 }},
       {{- $.Values.ingress.CIDR1 }},
       {{- $.Values.ingress.CIDR3 }}"
```

with values.yaml

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: {}
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: []
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

  CIDR1: A.B.C.D/32,A.B.C.D/32
  CIDR2: A.B.C.D/32,A.B.C.D/32
  CIDR3: A.B.C.D/32,A.B.C.D/32
```